# How do I know local repository is behind the origin and FF is possible in TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

In console I may perform `git status` and see something like:

```
>git status
# On branch foobar
# Your branch is behind 'origin/foobar' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
```

How am I supposed to do the same in TortoiseGit?

PS: this question is about GUI usage only - how to do that in pure GUI.

**UPD**:

also the information about FF is significant

**UPD 2**

Bounty to a person who could help finding if FF is available for an upstream merge :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you meant TortoiseGit, i have attached an image which will tell u how many commits you are behind by with its commit hash (https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfUHU.png)

[image: Equivalent to status, Browse References]

Comment: I cannot see "tell u how many commits you are behind" on your screenshots

Comment: Yes, it will not show you how many commits you are behind like the command line. But you know from status on which hash you are on, and which is the latest hash, and the difference between the hashes, is the number of commits you are behind.

Comment: "and the difference between the hashes, is the number of commits you are behind" --- I don't see that difference as well. Also - it's not possible to know if fast-forward is possible (and it is important)

Comment: for example:
[hash 1 : 98435kjsdfjk7 (lastest hash)]
[hash 2 : 98kjfhkjsdfkj]
[hash 3 : sdjkfsjdfjk (i'm here)] 

The difference is not shown as such, we have to figure it out visually ourselves. So i can see it in the list and figure out, and yes we cannot find out if its fast-forwardable or not ..

Comment: well, +1 to you for investigation and sad that FF info isn't available

Comment: If you don't see "Browse Reference" in the context menu, press the SHIFT key before Right Mouse Clicking and it'll show.